# Undeclared assignment of variables are accessed outside of the function scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

Generally variables(Variable Declaration) declared inside a function can be accessed only by that function & its inner functions.But, Undeclared Assignment of a variable inside a function is accessed outside of the function Scope in **JavaScript** by making it a global variable. Why does this happen ?

```
var hello = function() {
   number = 45;
};
hello();
console.log(number);    // 45 is printed in the console
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the spec says so.

Add `"use strict";` to the top of your file or function to disallow this.

Answer (score 1):

Assignments to variables that do not appear in `var` declarations are treated as assignments to global variables (properties of the global context). In "strict" mode, such assignments raise an error.

That's just how JavaScript works. If `number` were declared properly, it would not be visible globally:

```
var hello = function() {
   var number = 45;
}
hello();
console.log(number);    // undefined is printed in the console
```